# Problem with scss: some styles are not applied

Tags: html, css, sass

I'm doing a tutorial from **DesignCourse** on YouTube about **SVG Clip Path** and in my .scss file i have many styles but styles after line 38 are not even applying and when i checked code with his, i saw that his code is the same as mine and i don't know why those styles are not applying. I tried switching into Incognito mode and switching browsers but none of that helped **(I do not get any errors in Visual Studio Code and in browser console)**.

Here is link to that tutorial: **https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x9_ULV1vjQE&list=WL&index=42**

Here is my .scss file:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito&display=swap');

body, html {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: "Nunito";
    background: #220954;
}

.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;

    nav {
        width: 20%;
        float: right;
        background-color: #5923c6;
        height: calc(100vh - 4em);
        font-size: 1.4em;
        line-height: 1.5em;
        color: white;
        padding: 2em;
        //clip-path: url("#clipPath");

        ul {
            list-style-type: none;
            padding: 0;

            a {
                text-decoration: none;
                display: block;
                padding: 1em 0;
                font-weight: bold;
                color: white;
            }


            p {
                color: red;
            }
        }
    }

    h1 {
        color: white;
        margin: 2em;
        font-size: 5em;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
    }

    button {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        margin: 2em;
        font-size: 1.4em;
        background: none;
        border: 3px solid purple;
        color: white;
        padding: 1em;
        cursor: pointer;
        outline: none;

        &:hover {
            background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 01);
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>CLIPPY</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
</head>
<body>
    <button id="open">Open Nav</button>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About Me</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Dolorem recusandae aperiam est nulla veritatis magnam dolores, totam perspiciatis unde, mollitia vel exercitationem quas reprehenderit qui deserunt? Illum ipsam eveniet exercitationem?</p>
        </nav>
    </div>

    <h1>Bro, wooooooahh</h1>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're sass is exactly 38 lines long.

Comment: in my editor it shows that it is 73 lines long. Do i have brackets wrong?

Comment: Then you didn't copy all of your sass

Comment: you have to scroll down on sass code because there is more

Comment: Have you compiled that scss code to css after adding new styles?

Comment: i have extension that compiles sass every time i save it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question isn't real clear but I presume you're talking about your h1, and button styles not being applied.

Your SCSS has these styles defined as children of the .wrapper style, meaning they are compiled as `.wrapper h1` and `.wrapper button`.  This type of selector requires the elements to be defined as children of your wrapper div in the HTML.

In your HTML however these elements are not contained within the wrapper div, they are siblings to it.

You need to either move the HTML into the wrapper div, or move your SCSS definitions outside of the .wrapper class.

The youtube video you are following has misleading code due to a mistake.  There is an extra brace on line 37 visible at [7:09](https://youtu.be/x9_ULV1vjQE?list=WL&t=429).  This extra brace causes his future styles appear to be members of the .wrapper class by their indentation level when they really are not.